# Which graphics packages to download using Ubuntu command line for FORTRAN simulations?

Tags: command-line, graphics, fortran

I've been told to convert some FORTRAN code to C or Python. I don't have previous experience with FORTRAN. So I understand the concept of the given code:

```
subroutine photo(dp,dw,gc,dc,white,blue,icolor,p,prob,lat,ini,igr)
  implicit double precision (a-h,o-z)
  dimension prob(lat+2,lat+2)
  integer white(3),icolor(3),blue(3)
  integer dp,dw,gc,dc,pixmap,rad
  integer magni, istx, isty,ipos
    magni=8
ipos=100
    istx=ipos
    isty=lat*magni+ipos
icol=65000
    call xsetfg(dp,gc,dc,white)
    call xfillrect(dp,pixmap,gc,0,0,8,8)
    call xsetfg(dp,gc,dc,icolor)

    do ll=2,lat+1
    do kk=2,lat+1

   icx=0
   icy=0
   icz=0

   if(prob(kk,ll).eq.1)then
      icx=0
      icy=0
      icz=0

icolor(1)=icx
icolor(2)=icy
icolor(3)=icz
call xsetfg(dp,gc,dc,icolor)
    call xfillrect(dp,pixmap,gc,istx+kk*magni,isty-ll*magni,8,8)
    endif

    if(prob(kk,ll).eq.0)then
      icx=65000
      icy=65000
      icz=65000

icolor(1)=icx
icolor(2)=icy
icolor(3)=icz
call xsetfg(dp,gc,dc,icolor)
    call xfillrect(dp,pixmap,gc,istx+kk*magni,isty-ll*magni,8,8)
    endif

    enddo
    enddo

    return
    end
```

But it seems I need to download some FORTRAN graphics libraries/packages to execute the code as it gives many `undefined reference` errors if I run it in CodeBlocks along with gfortran.

So can someone tell me which graphics packages to download using the Ubuntu command line terminal?

Comment: Do you have only the source file provided, or are there other fortran sources? The main program is missing, and the functions `xsetfg`and `xfillrect`as well, and I could not find them in any library. If these are not the problem, please add more information to your question, especially what references are missed.

Comment: @ridgy Yes, I only have the source file provided. Do I have to recreate the functions `xsetfg` and `xfillrect` ? This is the whole code I was given: https://paste.ofcode.org/3aQe3F99ZEVqQHmySNQG7Gc

Comment: Usually, functions starting with "x" are part of the X11 libraries. But I could not find the functions needed (`xgetroot`, `xinit`, `xcreatepixmap`, `xfillrect`, `xsetfg` and maybe more) in the standard libraries. Maybe someone whom you got the source from can tell which libraries are needed? Or do you have the original compiler instructions? Writing the missing functions by yourself will be difficult if you are not familiar with X11.

Comment: Do you actually *need* to run this code to convert it to C? Perhaps you can deduce the function of the missing subroutines. For example, xsetfg sounds a lot like it sets the foreground color.